# How to do surface plot (with rich colormap) in Manim

Tags: python, animation, plot, octave, manim

How can I make a surface plot animation like this one:

[image]

The 3d plot is viewed from the top. I made that using GNU Octave.

How to do it in Manim? I only know it can make surface plot using checker board colormap. How to do it so the result will be similar as Matlab/Octave? With rich colormap. For example this colormap:
[image]

My plan is to do the computation in Octave, and then use the numerical result to make animation in Manim.